# SSRS in firefox not asking for credentials

Tags: sql-server, firefox, reporting-services

I have a 2012 SQL Server Reporting Server, I have various reports in it. When I access to the server via Chrome Browser (http://XX.XX.X.XX/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx) ask me for credentials as normally, but when I access the same URL via Firefox it does not, it just only displays a blank page. It also asks authentication normally in IE.

Some details:

MAC OS X 10.9.4 
Firefox version 32.0.3

Does anyone have idea of what can be happening?
Thanks for the time.

EDIT: Firefox in windows is working correctly with the same version I have in MAC.

EDIT: Updated to latest version of Firefox 33.0, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, is in this question:

https://superuser.com/questions/770897/firefox-does-not-prompt-for-password-for-http-authenticated-sites-how-to-make-i

I set to true the network.negotiate-auth.allow-insecure-ntlm-v1 option in my about:config and is working all normally again.